# Can we create UI Element in ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view, model, viewmodel

I have some confused about create ui element in viewmodel ? If yes then how can it possible ?

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 3):

No, in the mvvm pattern the viewmodel is only responsible for providing data and state.

You can theoretically have many views connected to the same viewmodel; A wpf-view for graphics displays and a command-line for text-mode for instance. If you think like that it makes sense where to put which functionality.

If you want to create UI objects programatically, you do that in the views code-behind. You are absolutely allowed to do it there and hook into any events just as you would have in a traditional forms project.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do that? Do you need to generate a dynamic UI at runtime?

The ViewModel isn't for UI elements, though it can hold backing data elements for the UI element (like list of items for a combo box).

UI is a job for the View. You can generate XAML at runtime, but I would not create it "in ViewModel" I would create a separate, distinct presenter or controller class, or use XAML code behind logic. You can reflect over the ViewModel to generate XAML, but I would limit the ViewModel to data and mediation between the View and the Model and keep all UI separate.

I am not a WPF expert, I'm just answering from the general best-practices perspective of MVC/MVVM and the purpose of the ViewModel. Theoretically, your ViewModel should be reusable across multiple UI presentation layers (ASP.NET/Razor/XAML) so avoid UI specific markup in the ViewModel. Limit it to properties, containers, methods, data access calls or service calls, etc.